# Impala - out of memory exception. Slow queries

Tags: performance, memory, impala

Can someone help me. I'm running a cluster of 5 Impala-Nodes for my Api. Now I get a lot of 'out of memory' Exceptions when I run queries.

```
Failed to get minimum memory reservation of 3.94 MB on daemon r5c3s4.colo.vm:22000 for query 924d155863398f6b:c4a3470300000000 because it would exceed an applicable memory limit. Memory is likely oversubscribed. Reducing query concurrency or configuring admission control may help avoid this error. Memory usage:
, node=[r4c3s2]
Process: Limit=55.00 GB Total=49.79 GB Peak=49.92 GB, node=[r4c3s2]
  Buffer Pool: Free Buffers: Total=0, node=[r4c3s2]
  Buffer Pool: Clean Pages: Total=4.21 GB, node=[r4c3s2]
  Buffer Pool: Unused Reservation: Total=-4.21 GB, node=[r4c3s2]
  Free Disk IO Buffers: Total=1.19 GB Peak=1.52 GB, node=[r4c3s2]
```

However, it says there are just used 23.83 GB of 150.00 GB. Also the queries became really slow. This problem occurred out of nowhere. Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Here are all memory infromation I got from the "/memz?detailed=true" page of one node:

```
Memory Usage
Memory consumption / limit: 23.83 GB / 150.00 GB
Breakdown`enter code here`

Process: Limit=150.00 GB Total=23.83 GB Peak=58.75 GB
  Buffer Pool: Free Buffers: Total=72.69 MB
  Buffer Pool: Clean Pages: Total=0
  Buffer Pool: Unused Reservation: Total=-71.94 MB
  Free Disk IO Buffers: Total=1.61 GB Peak=1.67 GB
  RequestPool=root.default: Total=20.77 GB Peak=59.92 GB
    Query(2647a4f63d37fdaa:690ad3b500000000): Reservation=20.67 GB ReservationLimit=120.00 GB OtherMemory=101.21 MB Total=20.77 GB Peak=20.77 GB
      Unclaimed reservations: Reservation=71.94 MB OtherMemory=0 Total=71.94 MB Peak=139.94 MB
      Fragment 2647a4f63d37fdaa:690ad3b50000001c: Reservation=0 OtherMemory=114.48 KB Total=114.48 KB Peak=855.48 KB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=9): Total=102.12 KB Peak=102.12 KB
          Exprs: Total=102.12 KB Peak=102.12 KB
        EXCHANGE_NODE (id=8): Total=0 Peak=0
        DataStreamRecvr: Total=0 Peak=0
        DataStreamSender (dst_id=10): Total=872.00 B Peak=872.00 B
        CodeGen: Total=3.50 KB Peak=744.50 KB
      Fragment 2647a4f63d37fdaa:690ad3b500000014: Reservation=0 OtherMemory=243.31 KB Total=243.31 KB Peak=1.57 MB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=3): Total=102.12 KB Peak=102.12 KB
          Exprs: Total=102.12 KB Peak=102.12 KB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=7): Total=119.12 KB Peak=119.12 KB
          Exprs: Total=119.12 KB Peak=119.12 KB
        EXCHANGE_NODE (id=6): Total=0 Peak=0
        DataStreamRecvr: Total=0 Peak=0
        DataStreamSender (dst_id=8): Total=6.81 KB Peak=6.81 KB
        CodeGen: Total=7.25 KB Peak=1.34 MB
      Fragment 2647a4f63d37fdaa:690ad3b50000000c: Reservation=2.32 GB OtherMemory=349.48 KB Total=2.32 GB Peak=2.32 GB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=2): Total=119.12 KB Peak=119.12 KB
          Exprs: Total=119.12 KB Peak=119.12 KB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=5): Reservation=2.32 GB OtherMemory=199.74 KB Total=2.32 GB Peak=2.32 GB
          Exprs: Total=120.12 KB Peak=120.12 KB
        EXCHANGE_NODE (id=4): Total=0 Peak=0
        DataStreamRecvr: Total=336.00 B Peak=549.14 KB
        DataStreamSender (dst_id=6): Total=6.44 KB Peak=6.44 KB
        CodeGen: Total=15.85 KB Peak=3.10 MB
      Fragment 2647a4f63d37fdaa:690ad3b500000004: Reservation=18.29 GB OtherMemory=100.52 MB Total=18.38 GB Peak=18.38 GB
        AGGREGATION_NODE (id=1): Reservation=18.29 GB OtherMemory=334.12 KB Total=18.29 GB Peak=18.29 GB
          Exprs: Total=148.12 KB Peak=148.12 KB
        HDFS_SCAN_NODE (id=0): Total=100.17 MB Peak=178.15 MB
          Exprs: Total=4.00 KB Peak=4.00 KB
        DataStreamSender (dst_id=4): Total=6.75 KB Peak=6.75 KB
        CodeGen: Total=9.72 KB Peak=2.92 MB
  RequestPool=fe-eval-exprs: Total=0 Peak=12.00 KB
  Untracked Memory: Total=1.44 GB

tcmalloc

------------------------------------------------
MALLOC:    24646559936 (23504.8 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +            0 (    0.0 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +    725840992 (  692.2 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
MALLOC: +      4726720 (    4.5 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist
MALLOC: +    208077600 (  198.4 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists
MALLOC: +    105918656 (  101.0 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =  25691123904 (24501.0 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)
MALLOC: +  53904392192 (51407.2 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =  79595516096 (75908.2 MiB) Virtual address space used
MALLOC:
MALLOC:         133041              Spans in use
MALLOC:            842              Thread heaps in use
MALLOC:           8192              Tcmalloc page size
------------------------------------------------
Call ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).
Bytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.

System

Physical Memory: 252.41 GB
Transparent Huge Pages Config:
  enabled: always [madvise] never
  defrag: [always] madvise never
  khugepaged defrag: 1

Process and system memory metrics
Name    Value   Description
memory.anon-huge-page-bytes     19.01 GB    Total bytes of anonymous (a.k.a. transparent) huge pages used by this process.
memory.mapped-bytes     113.09 GB   Total bytes of memory mappings in this process (the virtual memory size).
memory.num-maps     18092   Total number of memory mappings in this process.
memory.rss  24.51 GB    Resident set size (RSS) of this process, including TCMalloc, buffer pool and Jvm.
memory.thp.defrag   [always] madvise never  The system-wide 'defrag' setting for Transparent Huge Pages.
memory.thp.enabled  always [madvise] never  The system-wide 'enabled' setting for Transparent Huge Pages.
memory.thp.khugepaged-defrag    1   The system-wide 'defrag' setting for khugepaged.
memory.total-used   23.83 GB    Total memory currently used by TCMalloc and buffer pool.
Buffer pool memory metrics
Name    Value   Description
buffer-pool.clean-page-bytes    0   Total bytes of clean page memory cached in the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.clean-pages     0   Total number of clean pages cached in the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.clean-pages-limit   12.00 GB    Limit on number of clean pages cached in the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.free-buffer-bytes   72.69 MB    Total bytes of free buffer memory cached in the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.free-buffers    177     Total number of free buffers cached in the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.limit   120.00 GB   Maximum allowed bytes allocated by the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.reserved    20.67 GB    Total bytes of buffers reserved by Impala subsystems
buffer-pool.system-allocated    20.67 GB    Total buffer memory currently allocated by the buffer pool.
buffer-pool.unused-reservation-bytes    71.94 MB    Total bytes of buffer reservations by Impala subsystems that are currently unused
JVM aggregate memory metrics
Name    Value   Description
jvm.total.committed-usage-bytes     1.45 GB     Jvm total Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.total.current-usage-bytes   903.10 MB   Jvm total Current Usage Bytes
jvm.total.init-usage-bytes  1.92 GB     Jvm total Init Usage Bytes
jvm.total.max-usage-bytes   31.23 GB    Jvm total Max Usage Bytes
jvm.total.peak-committed-usage-bytes    2.09 GB     Jvm total Peak Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.total.peak-current-usage-bytes  1.48 GB     Jvm total Peak Current Usage Bytes
jvm.total.peak-init-usage-bytes     1.92 GB     Jvm total Peak Init Usage Bytes
jvm.total.peak-max-usage-bytes  31.41 GB    Jvm total Peak Max Usage Bytes
JVM heap memory metrics
Name    Value   Description
jvm.heap.committed-usage-bytes  1.37 GB     Jvm heap Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.current-usage-bytes    827.25 MB   Jvm heap Current Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.init-usage-bytes   2.00 GB     Jvm heap Init Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.max-usage-bytes    26.67 GB    Jvm heap Max Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.peak-committed-usage-bytes     0   Jvm heap Peak Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.peak-current-usage-bytes   0   Jvm heap Peak Current Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.peak-init-usage-bytes  0   Jvm heap Peak Init Usage Bytes
jvm.heap.peak-max-usage-bytes   0   Jvm heap Peak Max Usage Bytes
JVM non-heap memory metrics
Name    Value   Description
jvm.non-heap.committed-usage-bytes  76.90 MB    Jvm non-heap Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.current-usage-bytes    75.68 MB    Jvm non-heap Current Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.init-usage-bytes   2.44 MB     Jvm non-heap Init Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.max-usage-bytes    -1.00 B     Jvm non-heap Max Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.peak-committed-usage-bytes     0   Jvm non-heap Peak Committed Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.peak-current-usage-bytes   0   Jvm non-heap Peak Current Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.peak-init-usage-bytes  0   Jvm non-heap Peak Init Usage Bytes
jvm.non-heap.peak-max-usage-bytes   0   Jvm non-heap Peak Max Usage Bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process: Limit=150.00 GB Total=23.83 GB Peak=58.75 GB
```

this caused by `memory limit`   `Memorylimit exceeded`

change those setting `memory.soft_limit_in_bytes`  ,`memory.limit_in_bytes`  `mem_limit` ,`default_pool_mem_limit`  value to `0` or `-1`

1 or 0 represents unlimited .